# MySQL - Query last six weeks of data

Tags: mysql

In order to calculate projected sales for a given day, I need to query the last six weeks of data for a given day. For example, if I want projected sales for Friday, I need to query data from the last six Fridays only.

I'm assuming there is a way to do this within a query, just not sure exactly how. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated, as always.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of date/datetime information are you storing with each sale?

Comment: Sales are stored in a DATE format. So for example, if I wanted projected sales for today, I would need 2012-02-17, 2012-02-10, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a limit.

```
SELECT date, sales FROM yourtable WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date)=6 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 6;
```

EDIT: To get this relative to today, just add CURDATE()

```
SELECT date, sales FROM yourtable WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date)=DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of different MySQL date and time functions to achieve this. Your query could look something like this:

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE DAYOFWEEK(table.date) = DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) ORDER BY table.date DESC LIMIT 6
```

Of course you can replace `CURDATE()` with the date that you are trying to predict.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From table Where date_field > DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -42 DAY)
```

That's about what you will need to do.

I just seen you wanted to query only a particular day of each week.  Give me a moment and I'll update this.

Nevermind, I'm not going to edit this.  Bobby has your answer for you.  You just need to place variables in there through your script as needed.  +1 Bobby.